# Performing studio effects on a live ensemble

Tags: performing, studio

In a recent Adam Neely video he had his brass section performing as though their audio was being pumped by a side chain controlled by the bass drum - they'd manually duck their volume on each bass drum hit, and then play louder for the remainder of the note.

What other studio techniques  could you realistically perform live on an acoustic ensemble? I've asked before about performing reverberation…

Comment: This is what we musicians call "having a conductor,"  or  "having dynamic markings in our sheet music."    If by "studio technique" you mean signal processing, then sure you can't make a flute sound "plucked" followed by transitioning from sine to square wave form.  I don't really see the point here.

Comment: Interesting idea to fake compression in this way. Certain kinds of delay effects could be faked. Can't think of much else.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - there is a technique where a trumpet player plays into the open bell of a tuba while the tuba player just waggles their valves and it sounds like a _mandolin_. So you can make a brass instrument sound plucked…

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS that I gotta see!  (and hear)